# Obtaining kerning information

Tags: c++, gdi+, gdi, kerning

How can I obtain kerning information for GDI to then use in [GetKerningPairs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that

> The number of pairs in the lpkrnpair array. If the font has more than
>   nNumPairs kerning pairs, the function returns an error.

However, I do not know how many pairs to pass in, and I don't see a way to query for it.

EDIT #2

Here is my fill application that I have also tried, this is always producing 0 for any font for the number of pairs. GetLastError will always return 0 also.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Gdiplus.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Gdiplus;

int main(void)
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    Font* myFont = new Font(L"Times New Roman", 12);
    Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(256, 256, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
    Graphics* g = new Graphics(bitmap);

    //HDC hdc = g->GetHDC();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    SelectObject(hdc, myFont->Clone());
    DWORD numberOfKerningPairs = GetKerningPairs(hdc, INT_MAX, NULL );

    cout << GetLastError() << endl;
    cout << numberOfKerningPairs << endl;

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
I tried to do the following, however, it still gave me 0.

```
Font* myFont = new Font(L"Times New Roman", 10);
Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(256, 256, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
Graphics* g = new Graphics(bitmap);

SelectObject(g->GetHDC(), myFont);
//DWORD numberOfKerningPairs = GetKerningPairs( g->GetHDC(), -1, NULL );
DWORD numberOfKerningPairs = GetKerningPairs( g->GetHDC(), INT_MAX, NULL );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you are passing in a `Gdiplus::Font` and not a HFONT for `SelectObject`. You need to convert `Font* myFont` into a `HFONT`, then pass that `HFONT` into SelectObject.

First, to convert a `Gdiplus::Font` into a `HFONT`, you need to get the [LOGFONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901140.aspx) from the `Gdiplus::Font`. Once you do this, the rest is simple. The working solution to get number of kerning pairs is

```
Font* gdiFont = new Font(L"Times New Roman", 12);

Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(256, 256, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
Graphics* g = new Graphics(bitmap);

LOGFONT logFont;
gdiFont->GetLogFontA(g, &logFont);
HFONT hfont = CreateFontIndirect(&logFont);

HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
SelectObject(hdc, hfont);
DWORD numberOfKerningPairs = GetKerningPairs(hdc, INT_MAX, NULL );
```

As you can tell, the only functional change I gave was to creating a `FONT`.

Answer (score 3):

You first call it with the third parameter set to NULL, in which case it returns the number of kerning pairs for the font. You then allocate memory, and call it again passing that buffer:

```
int num_pairs = GetKerningPairs(your_dc, -1, NULL);

KERNINGPAIR *pairs = malloc(sizeof(*pairs) * num_pairs);

GetKernningPairs(your_dc, num_pairs, pairs);
```

Edit: I did a quick test (using MFC by not GDI+) and got what seemed like reasonable results. The code I used was:

```
CFont font;
font.CreatePointFont(120, "Times New Roman", pDC);
pDC->SelectObject(&font);

int pairs = pDC->GetKerningPairs(1000, NULL);

CString result;
result.Format("%d", pairs);
pDC->TextOut(10, 10, result);
```

This printed out `116` as the result.

Comment: For that to work it would seem I would need to use my fonts dc, how could I get that?

Comment: @chadb: create a DC, and select the font into it. You normally want to use a DC compatible with the ultimate target, so if the output is going to the screen, create a DC compatible with the screen. If it's going to the printer, create one for the printer.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and I still get 0. I updated my code above since it does not fit here.

Comment: @chadb: I've edited some test code into the answer. Doing a bit of testing, it appears that the second parameter, which really should be ignored when the third is NULL, isn't ignored after all, so you need to set it to a positive number to get a result back. I tried both 1000 and INT_MAX, and both seemed to be fine.

Comment: I tried INT_MAX and that unfortunately did not work either, it still returns 0 with GDI+.

Comment: @chadb: In that case, I'd probably use the plain GDI function(s) to create a DC, select the font into that, and retrieve the kerning pairs using it (just be sure it refers to the same target device). Probably want to wrap that into a function to restrict that kind of clumsiness to one place.

Comment: I have tried doing that too, with several different functions. Including CreateCompatibleDC based upon the graphics HDC. I also tried to clone the font in case it was causing some sort of issue, it seems as if that function just does not work or I am doing something terribly wrong (though the code I posted above is what I am doing for my test case). I am doing this in a console window.

Comment: Do you happen to know why the updated code would always return 0 for every font possible?

Comment: @chadb: No, not really -- I haven't been able to duplicate the problem (though I'll admit I haven't tried it with GDI+ yet).

Comment: hmm, this seemss to be a very tricky problem. I have my entire program up top in case anyone else wants to try to duplicate it.